# Python 2.7 (Anaconda 2) - IndentationError: unexpected indent Notepad++ auto separating code

Tags: python, notepad++

Okay, so this code is for an online class, and I feel the issue is caused by Notepad++, but I can't prove anything.

Actual Error is:
`[Anaconda2] C:\Users\ia566\Desktop\Python>python countorgdb.py
  File "countorgdb.py", line 20
    print pieces
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Here is a picture of Notepad++:

[Notepad++ Screen Shot With Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaCXd.jpg)

[Notepad++ with line deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33YMY.jpg)

Notice how the file tree changes. Any addition to the code causes an extra branch in the file tree and thus an Indention Error.

Full Code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('jbemaildb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: ') : continue
    pieces = line.split()
    org = pieces[1]
    print org
    # Here is were I a am trying to add a print statement and more code.
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ', (org, ))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (org, count) 
            VALUES ( ?, 1 )''', (org, ) )
    else : 
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count=count+1 WHERE org = ?', 
            (org, ))
    # This statement commits outstanding changes to disk each 
    # time through the loop - the program can be made faster 
    # by moving the commit so it runs only after the loop completes
    conn.commit()

# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT org, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

print
print "Counts:"
for row in cur.execute(sqlstr) :
    print str(row[0]), row[1]

cur.close()
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing to make Notepad++ so angry. I just want to be able to add to my code.

Comment: I wonder if turning code folding off would make a difference. I'm in v6.8.9... Settings > Preferences, select Editing, set Folder Margin Style to none.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation Error occurs when you are not using spaces or tabs properly. You should indent your code with four spaces. Try it out and see if it helps.